# Validate ZipCode in Grails Domain?

Tags: validation, grails, grails-orm

I have a Grails domain containing a zipCode field:

```
class SomeClass {

 String zipCode

}
```

A valid zip code in my def is that it is either blank or contains only of numbers.

**How do I validate that the zipCode field is either blank or a valid zip code containing only numbers?**

Comment: It depends on what you consider a 'valid' zip code. I assume you are just dealing with US addresses since you say 'zip code' and 'numbers only'. However, even if you validate that it contains only number and is exactly 5 digits you still don't know if it's technically a valid zip code for the city/state/county. If you need that level of validation you need to use either the data provided by the USPS (you have to subscribe to the database and pay for it) or use a service such as Cdyne. So, update your question to say what you mean by 'valid' for the best answer.

Comment: what issue do you have? any error? any particular problem? and what did you try?

Comment: A valid zip code in my def is that it is either blank or contains only of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
class SomeClass {

 String zipCode

 static constraints = {
   zipCode blank:true, validator:{ it ==~ /\d+/ }
 }
}
```

Comment: So, based on that the following is a valid zip code? 7. I don't think so.

Comment: As soon as the OP didn't provide his original attempts, I assume that he has no clue on how to define the constraints/validators at all. Practically, there's no such thing as a "valid zip code". There are existing zip codes and non-existing, although perfectly valid :) so the best way would be to check the validity against the lookup table

Comment: a regexp for a 1 or more digits. you can also specify the length of 5 by `/\d{5}/`

Comment: `/\d{5,}/` see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

Easy, easy.

```
String zipCode

static constraints = {
    zipCode(nullable:false, blank:false,validator:{zip, address ->
        //Check for 9 digit with - or 5 digit or just 9 digits
        if(zip ==~ /^(\d{5}-\d{4})|(\d{5})|(\d{9})$/) {
            return true
        }
        else {
            return "invalidZipFormat"
        }
    })


}
```

Comment: I just want to validate that the zip code is either blank or if not blank it must contain only of numbers.